# Select range of rows in query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a function that takes `page_size` and `skip` as arguments.  If `page_size = 10` and `skip = 2`, I want to select 10 rows starting at row 21.  I think this has to do with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.  How do I do this in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`limit`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.limit) and [`offset`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.offset) methods on the query.

```
session.query(...).limit(page_size).offset(skip)
```